# When hierophant druids enter the elemental planes, can they choose where they end up?

Tags: druid, adnd-2e, planes

So, Jeena is a hierophant druid. She has the ability to enter, move and survive in the elemental planes of fire and water.

She wants to visit the efreet in the City of Brass to negotiate some cosmically important treaties.

Later on, she needs to drop some components at her brother archmage's estate, floating in a bubble of air in the elemental plane of water.

Do hierophant druids choose where they enter the elemental planes?

Answer (score 3):

The RAW are, sadly, a bit lacking, but did ensure that you're looking at a 19th level heirophant druid.  From the PHB, 2nd ed:

> Rather than spells, spell-like powers are acquired.
>
> A 17th level heirophant druid can also enter the Elemental Plane of Earth at will.  The transference takes one round to complete.  This ability also provides the means to survive on that plane, move around, and return to the Prime Material Plane at will.  It does not confer similar abilities or immunities on the Prime Material Plane.
>
> 18th level:  The character gains the ability to enter and survive in the Elemental Plane of Fire.
>
> The character gains the ability to enter and survive the Elemental Plane of Water.

Given that the description of the ability doesn't mention how accurately your druid can move between the planes, we're forced to rely on the spell or spells the ability mimics.  Searching through the priest spell list, the only three viable candidates I could find were *plane shift*, *astral spell*, and *gate.*  Of them, the one which most closely resembles the druid ability is *plane shift*, since a portal isn't opened and the travel takes a single round.  In that case, you'd adhere to *plane shift*'s level of accuracy:

> Arriving a random distance from an intended destination is common.

It is entirely possible that a different rulebook addresses these issues specifically, but if so, it isn't the *Dungeon Master's Guide* or the *Tome of Magic.* In the absence of such an authority, we'll go with the implied answer:

**Yes, but they often arrive off-target.**

Comment: One point of hierophants is that they burn so much XP to level up that their party members are well into epic-tier when they get these powers.

Answer (score 1):

The 2e core rulebooks do not provide a solid answer, nor does the Planescape campaign set or expansion *The Inner Planes*. Likewise, *The Complete Druid's Handbook*, a 2e sourcebook, does not provide an answer in the main text, but it has an appendix for AD&D 1e druids, where we get a clue. The appendix discusses hierophant druids up to level 23, at which point they are described to obtain the ability to enter not only any of the inner planes, but also the Plane of Concordant Opposition (true neutral Outer Plane). Unfortunately, while nothing is described regarding the particular choice of target destination, the clue we get  beyond what is in the PHB is the following sentence (pg 121):

> It takes the druid **one round to shift into a plane** (or back to the Prime Material Plane), but the character can stay there as long as desired.

Note the use of the word *shift*. We can complement this clue with information we can gather from the 1e *Manual of Planes* (pg 22). There, the power of hierophant druids is described as "temporary vortices or gates", and these are implicitly likened to the behaviour of "such spells such as *plane shift*". So it would be meaningful to use the rules that govern the *plane shift*.

Hence we now turn to 2e PHB (pg 224) for the description of the spell *plane shift*. It mentions:

> Note that **pinpoint accuracy is rarely achieved**; arriving a random distance from an intended destination is common.